# Forecasting from a time series mixture model which is an average of other models

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, mixture-model

I'm trying to fit a mixture model to a time series in order to do forecasts (averaging an `arima`, an `ets` and an `stlf` model).

Is there an R package that can handle this?

I've managed to find a number of packages that can handle mixture models, but they do not include forecasting.

In case there is no such package, is there a nice way to calculate the prediction intervals (the forecasts themselves will just be the average of the means).

Thanks!